# Load different layout / dimensions depending on screen size and resolution in Android

Tags: android, layout, screen, tablet

I am trying to load a different xml file for the layout and dimens in Android. I have tried creating an xlarge folder (for 10 inch tablet) and large folder (for 7 inch tablet). So the folder are called values-xlarge and values-large or values-xlarge and values-large. The 10 inch tablet has a density of 224 ppi.

If I use these layout files, the layout file from the values-large folder is used for the 10 inch tablet. How can I load a different design for 7 and 10 inch tablets? And which appendix should be used to the folder? I have found small, medium, large, ..., sw700dp, sw600dp and mdpi, hdpi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use sw720dp, sw350dp-land, sw350dp, etc.
The layout in the folder will be used for a screen with the smallest width (sw...) of 720dp, etc. ie. sw700dp will be used for screens with 700dp or more or up until the next sw???dp layout.

It is in Display Independent Pixels, not regular pixels.  ie.  pixel width divided by the screen dpi.  You can also add a -land or -port to only use this layout if it is landscape or portrait.
Check out this link for more information.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes